# Which is best for mobile application testing? Manual or Automation?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, mobile

I am currently working in Mobile Testing (Manual), I just want to know which type of testing best suits for mobile apps (Manual or Automation)? Kindly provide suggestions on this.

Comment: As the answers put, there isn't a great answer to this. It suffers from two problems. One is that it's mostly based in opinion, and the other is that it's a very broad question. That's not to say that you're completely out of luck. What I would recommend is taking the actual challenges and problems you have, whether it's something hard to test with your manual tests, or a struggle getting your automated tests running, and post for help on that specific problem. That would be the best way to get quality results (cue terrible puns!) out of this SE site. =)

Comment: answer depends on your definition of "best"

Answer (score 3):

A mixture of both, there is no 'best'.

Answer (score 2):

To test mobile applications is very hard. You has so many different devices and operating systems. In some cases you have to test older versions of the application too, to be sure they work with a new backend or something like that. This produce a lot of combinations.

No, you can not covering all of these combinations manual, neither with automation. But automation can help you to coverage more combinations in the same time.

Automation do not exists to supersede manual testing. The best way is to have both. My opinion is, that you automate the regression tests, because you execute them over and over again. But maybe you know what kind of tests you most execute. Whatever, if you automate these tests, you save a lot of time and recurring work.

Take the decision to automate tests for mobile is one thing. Find a proper tool another. On the market exists a few open source tools and a lot of commercial tools. You must invest a lot of time to evaluate what tool is the correct for you. Take the time!

Maybe you should also know, that you have a lot to do at the beginning of automation. But the more you automate, the less effort you will have each week or month. Automation is for a long term solution.